# Use autofs on host with Docker

Tags: debian, docker, cifs, autofs

I'm mounting CIFS share on a host to `/mnt/nas` using autofs.
On the host I'm running a PHP Docker container.
I can mount the `/mnt/nas` to this container using `volumes` inside a *docker-compose.yml*.

The problem is that it seems that the PHP process inside the container does not trigger the mount. I can verify this by setting the `LOGGING="debug"` on the host.

Why Docker does not trigger the mount ? How can I fix that ?
Is there a better solution I didn't think about (I can't change switch from CIFS or whatever) ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting mount-propagation to "shared" ?
If it is still not working then - I have had that problem recently but a reboot of the VM fixed it (temporarily?).
Its SUSE (12.5) - which I really don't prefer anyway. Had no troubles with other distributions.